# Submit form on radio button check

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How can I Submit the form `sAddToBasket` if a radio inside the form `radioform` gets checked ?

```
<form name="radioform" method="post" action="something1.php">
    <input type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit();" class="option--input" id="radio1" name="radio" value="">
    <input type="radio" onchange="this.form.submit();" class="option--input" id="radio2" name="radio" value="">
</form>
<form name="sAddToBasket" method="post" action="something2.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="option1" value="value1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="option2" value="value2"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get rid of the JS in the DOM (your `onchange=...`) and do something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("form[name=radioform] input").on("change", function() {
    $("form[name=sAddtoBasket").submit();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like this

```
<form name="radioform" method="post" action="something1.php"> <input type="radio" onchange="document.getElementById('sAddToBasket').submit();" class="option--input" id="radio1" name="radio" value=""> <input type="radio" onchange="document.getElementById('sAddToBasket').submit();" class="option--input" id="radio2" name="radio" value=""> </form>

 <form id='sAddToBasket' name="sAddToBasket" method="post" action="something2.php"> <input type="hidden" name="option1" value="value1"/> <input type="hidden" name="option2" value="value2"/> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

onchange you can call a js function like below.

```
<input type="radio" onchange="formSubmit(this)" class="option--input" id="radio1" name="radio" value="">

<form id="sAddToBasket">

</form>

<script>
function formSubmit(radioObj){
  if(radioObj.checked){
    document.getElementById("sAddToBasket").submit();

  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a class to the radio buttons.

```
<form name="radioform" method="post" action="something1.php">
    <input type="radio"  class="option--input subForm" id="radio1" name="radio" value="">
    <input type="radio"  class="option--input subForm" id="radio2" name="radio" value="">
</form>
```

and on the script use this:

```
 $(function(){
$('.subForm').click(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")
$('form[name=sAddtoBasket]').submit();

})
})
```